# Correct way to pass and call a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

In using an external sdk in node, I noticed I was writing a lot of repeated code. E.g.:

```
async function one(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sdk.one(function(err, req, res) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

async function two(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sdk.two(function(err, req, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

I wanted to simplify and abstract that to make it cleaner and thought of this:

```
async function runner(fn, params?): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const _CB = cb.bind({ resolve, reject });
    if (params) {
      return fn(params, _CB);
    }

    return fn(_CB);
  });
}

const one = async (): Promise<any> => {
  return runner(sdk.one);
};

const two = async (): Promise<any> => {
  return runner(sdk.two);
};
```

I get an error on running this though, i.e. `this.helper is not a function`. The problem, I believe, is that Javascript passes by value. So, when I run `fn(_CB)` inside runner and it tries to reference a function on its parent, `this.helper`, it doesn't know what `this` is because fn is literally just a copied block of code. Actually, before I thought of this, I tried to `util.Promisify` the sdk functions, but I get the same error as I do here.

I thought of this workaround, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

```
async function runner(fn, params?): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const _CB = cb.bind({ resolve, reject });
    if (params) {
      return fn(params, _CB);
    }

    return fn(_CB);
  });
}

const one = async (): Promise<any> => {
  return runner((x) => sdk.one(x));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the 'correct' or most optimal way to do it, but here's what I ended up doing in case anybody has a similar problem:

```
const sdk = new Sdk({ creds });

function runner(fn): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cb = (err, req, res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res);
    return fn(cb);
  });
}

function list(): Promise<any> {
  return runner(sdk.namespace1.list.bind(sdk.namespace1));
}

function create(param1: string, param2: string): Promise<any> {
  return runner(sdk.namespace2.create.bind(sdk.namespace2, {
    object: { param1, param2 },
  }));
}
```

It's probably pretty similar to what `util.promisify` does, just that this sdk is odd. Will probably end up renaming it to something promise-y.

Answer (score 0):

Are you losing scope when the sdk tries to call you back? You can use arrow functions to preserve scope in these calls. It works in a similar way to your intermediate `_CB` variable for older targets, but in up to date ECMAScript versions it is native.

```
async function one(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sdk.one((err, req, res) => { // Scope preserving arrow function
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}

async function two(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sdk.two((err, req, res) => { // and here
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't believe so. I put some loggers in the sdk function, and the problem is that `this instanceof sdk` == false.

Comment: Is `sdk` a member (on the same class as `one` and `two`? If so, you aren't calling it with `this.sdk` in your example?

Comment: Nope, it's declared in the top scope of the module, i.e. `const sdk = new SDK();`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are in javascript, the language that allows you to do almost anything. You can call functions dynamically

```
async function promisify(fnName): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sdk[fnName](function(err, req, res) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  });
}
```

and call it like `promisify('one')`

If you are using the current LTS 8.X Node version or bigger, you can use https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

If not, you can try to use the bluebird method for that: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

Comment: Haha thanks. I thought of this also, it works, but not so clean and very likely won't pass PR review :(.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `runner` function is mis-named, it should be renamed to `promisify`. Because as I see, you want to convert callback style functions to promised versions.

Check `util.promisify(original)` method in Node.js 8

> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Comment: Indeed, I tried `util.promisify(sdk.one)` before trying all this, but I got the same error. Thank you though!